# Firebug and post request

Tags: post, firebug

I have to make some automatic work with site. There is a form and I have to get post-request it makes. The problem is that firebug cleans information about request due to redirect to another page, so I haven't time to save post data information. Are there any ways to "freeze" it?

Comment: which operating system are you using?

Comment: @tsocks Linux. And Firefox browser with Firebug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can press the *persist* button.

[image: Firebug persist button]